# Finish off your meal, or finish up your meal?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In the situation where you want to tell a kid about the expected order of activities, which phrasal verb is correct?

1. You have to *finish **off*** your meal before you may watch the movie.

   or
2. You have to *finish **up*** your meal before you may watch the movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equivalent to each other.  However, to my ears (as a native speaker of American English), *finish up* sounds better in this context.

More examples:

> John finished up the dishes after dinner.
>
> John finished off a bottle of wine before going to bed.

Both have the sense of completion, but there is a subtle difference in feeling between the two.  *Finish off* feels much stronger, which is perhaps why it can also be used to mean *to kill something*.

> It was the blow to the head that finished him off, not the bullet wound.

Incidentally, *Finish up* is prefered intransitively, whereas *Finish off* is much rarer, at least in American English.

This sounds more natural than using *finish off*:

> Finish up so we can go.
>
> The race finished up in Boston.

Comment: Nice summary of the subtle distinction, which doesn't *only* apply when taken to the extremes of *finish off = kill*. I really wish people would address questions at this level to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where it would be worth explicitly making the point that if a learner takes on board the *nature* of the subtle distinction, they don't really need to learn *finish off = kill* as a special case "phrasal verb".

Comment: I suppose a lion killing a zebra is very literally _finishing off_ its meal…

Comment: To my (mostly) British ears, too, "finish off" sounds wrong.  In fact, I'm not sure I would ever use it except in the sense of "kill"

Answer (score 2):

I would just say "finish your meal"-- neither phrasal form adds anything here (unless you're writing a song).

"Finish up" is useful as an intransitive verb, to indicate that you are finishing whatever needs to be finished, rather than any particular subject.  "Finish off" is perhaps less obviously useful, but it connotes more finality.

Answer (score 1):

Although *finish off* and *finish up* do have some uses where they are not interchangeable, this is not one of them; here they both mean "bring a task to its completion".  So either one works just fine.  (In fact, *finish* with no preposition would work equally well in the example sentence.)

Comment: Could you please add examples where *finish off* and *finish up* are not interchangeable?

Comment: Between co-workers, past normal quitting time but with work yet to do: "You go home: I'll *finish up* here." Between deer-hunting buddies: "You need to find the buck you wounded and *finish* him *off."*

Comment: @Brian: Agreed only *finish **off*** can be used for *dispatch, kill*, but I don't see any reason not to use ***off*** in your example of co-workers talking about who will take care of the [few] items remaining to *complete a task*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I would agree with "finish *off* **the task**," but without direct object thus stated I think "finish *up"* is much the more established usage.

Comment: @Brian: Google NGrams seems to provide [at least some evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27ll+finish+up+the%3Aeng_us_2012%2CI%27ll+finish+up+the%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CI%27ll+finish+off+the%3Aeng_us_2012%2CI%27ll+finish+off+the%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20finish%20up%20the%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20finish%20off%20the%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20finish%20off%20the%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) that your distinction applies to AmE, but not to BrE.

Comment: I have no idea why that link doesn't seem to work, but what I searched for was **I'll finish up the:eng_us_2012,I'll finish up the:eng_gb_2012,I'll finish off the:eng_us_2012,I'll finish off the:eng_gb_2012**. Actually, it shows that AmE favours **finish up the**, where BrE favours **finish off the**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, those search keys appear designed to cover only the case with explicit direct object; at issue is the case *without.*

Comment: @Brian: I couldn't come up with a final word instead of ***the*** (indicating *object follows*) that would imply there *wasn't* an object. I tried *and* and *while*, but gave up when they didn't generate enough hits to graph. Intuitively though, I don't think Brits in general make much of a distinction (I certainly don't).